# Установка https для нового домена

Tags: https, домен

В осуществил переход сайта на новый домен с com.ua на ua, при этом для нового домена от хостинга cloudfalre был предоставлен и установлен ssl сертификат. 
На данный момент ряд браузеров как у меня так и у других пользователем при переходе на сайт https://motodnepr.ua отправляет следующую ошибку:

"Этот сайт не может обеспечить безопасное соединение.
На сайте motodnepr.ua используется неподдерживаемый протокол."

в Firefox сайт работает нормально по https и написано, что защищен.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробовал под виндой, ФФ, Я-браузер и ИЕ не выдают никаких ошибок

Comment: Можете прогнать тесты своего сайта на https://www.ssllabs.com